# Predicate editor issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

Inside my custom scroll view i have added predicate object as under. It is giving error in the methods predicateWithSubpredicates in debug stack. Here is my sample code please let me know if any error are present.

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    NSPredicateEditor *predicateeditor = [[NSPredicateEditor alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 150)];

    NSArray *leftExpressions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"], nil];

    NSAttributeType rightType = NSDateAttributeType;
    NSComparisonPredicateModifier modifier = NSAllPredicateModifier; //don't need "ANY" or "ALL"

    NSArray *operators = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithString:@"Today"],[NSString stringWithString:@"Tomorrow"],[NSString stringWithString:@"Next week"], nil];

    NSUInteger options = 0;

    NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate *rowTemplate = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate alloc] initWithLeftExpressions:leftExpressions rightExpressionAttributeType:rightType modifier:modifier operators:operators options:options];

    [predicateeditor setRowTemplates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowTemplate]];

    [rowTemplate release];

    [self addSubview:predicateeditor];

    [predicateeditor addRow:nil];

    [predicateeditor displayValuesForRow:1];

    [predicateeditor release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, this is going to define a predicate like this:

```
ALL date {"Today", "Tomorrow", "Next Week"} {a user-entered date}
```

I hope you can see that this is non-sensical.

For starters, if you really mean that `//don't need "ANY" or "ALL"`, then you shouldn't be be using `NSAllPredicateModifier`.  You should be using `NSDirectPredicateModifier`.

Also, the things that are allowed to go in the `operators` array are `NSNumber` objects that box one of the built-in [predicate operator values](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/Reference/NSComparisonPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001189-BBCHHCAD).

So: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My first concern is replacing the predefined operator equivalent with my text. Say, for date on right expression i would like to have {Today, Tommorrow, Next week,...};

Comment: I got it... in templateViews i need to return an array which will contain objects of my choice. So, in the middle object i will return an nspopupbutton with my list items.... thanks for replying....